# Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 -- broken install?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, installation

I've installed the MS VC++ compiler (standalone, not the whole Visual Studio) as a compiler kit for Qt 5.7. Whenever I attempt to build even the most basic project, I get a long list of errors, complaining about undefined symbols.

In particular, things like `FLT_RADIX`, `FLT_MANT_DIG`, `FLT_DIG`, etc. are undefined. I checked the header files that are part of VC (installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include`) and noticed that `cfloat` (where these symbols would likely be defined) is just 284 bytes worth of zeroes. There are other header files that are in similar shape.

I tried repairing/reinstalling `visualcppbuildtools_full.exe`, all to no avail. How can I get a proper install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first install crashed and left some of the header files in a corrupt state. I manually cleared up the junk left behind by the MSVC uninstaller, then reinstalled. This fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi Tony the Pony, you can mark your workaround as answer, so other community members who have the same or similar issue can easier search this useful solution.